# Don't mentally understand how this inner loop works

Tags: c++

I know the output, but I couldn't understand how to increment the "*". 

 
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,rows;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>rows;
    for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        {
           cout<<"* ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I will be glad if you make me understand this inner loop, I know that the outer prints a new line, My question: How this inner loops increments stars?

Comment: The inner loop just outputs `i` number of stars based on the current value of `i` in the outer loop. If you enter 5 as the number of rows, the outer loop starts on i=1 and you'll see 1 star followed by a new line. Then i=2 and you'll see 2 stars followed by a new line, etc until you see 5 stars and a new line.

Comment: @Ultimater Why is it necessary to do 2 loops?

Comment: @Ultimater Why do I make a loop for printing a new line, for example I could use cout<<"* "<<endl;? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `rows` value is `5` that means `outer loop` will rotate `5` times.

```
for(i=1;i<=rows;++i) /** 1<=5 , 2<=5 .. 5<=5 **/
```

Inner loop is  `for(j=1;j<=i;++j)` , for each `i` value it will rotate from `1` to `i`

**i=1 :** inner loop condition will be

- `1<=1`  =>  1 times prints `*` and prints `\n` and  move back to outer loop

**i=2 :** inner loop condition will be

- `1<=2`  =>  prints `*`
- `2<=2`  =>  prints `*` and prints `\n` and move back to outer loop

**i=3 :** inner loop condition will be

- `1<=3` => prints `*`
- `2<=3` => prints `*`
- `3<=3` => prints `*` and prints `\n` and move back to outer loop and so on ..

my suggestion is before writing the program on console do some paperwork.

Answer (score 0):

If we enter rows == 5, then i will iterate from 1 to 5.
Then in each inner loop, j will iterate from 1 to i, so 1->1, 1->2, 1->3, 1->4, 1->5.
Thus you get your output.